# Adding item description from PostgreSQL/PostGIS data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, metadata

Is it possible to have metadata or an item description with a dataset from a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database without using SDE?

I now see an XML-error when trying to view the item description and there is no possibility to add or edit it.

Comment: No. That information is stored in the enterprise geodatabase metadata tables.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, using COMMENT ON.

[PostgreSQL supports comments through COMMENT ON.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html) I use them to load up the official names of all the columns from Census.

```
COMMENT ON TABLE mytable IS 'This is my table.';
COMMENT ON TABLE mytable IS NULL;
```

Comment: Are comments visible as feature class metadata in ArcGIS?  If not, this will not meet the OP's need.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not ArcGIS supports it, PostgreSQL certainly does. Maybe open an issue/feature request. If you're paying $1,500 for "enterprise" software, it should support the functionality of a free enterprise database? Right?